# Difficulty converting GROUP_CONCAT query from MySQL to H2 with DISTINCT keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

I am attempting to get a query that was previously used with MySQL to work with H2. The query does exactly as needed in MySQL (when the double quotes are replaced with backticks). It is as follows:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT "Id" ORDER BY "Id" SEPARATOR ' ') "Id", 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT "Course" ORDER BY "Id" SEPARATOR ' ') "Course",
        GROUP_CONCAT("Day/s" ORDER BY "Id" SEPARATOR ' ') "Day/s", 
        "Sect", 
        "Class Nbr" 
FROM SAMPLE 
GROUP BY "Class Nbr", "Sect"
```

The query in reality is programmatically generated, but that example captures what its purpose. Yes I am aware that using quotes around all column and table names to accommodate potential spaces is not ideal, but it is the approach that I have to work with at the moment.

The problem is that H2 does not seem to be interpreting the `DISTINCT` keyword, at least not like how MySQL was interpreting it. In H2, it is concatenating all aggregated values, regardless of whether they are distinct. For example, following the above example query, two duplicate `Id` entries get concatenated, which is not the behavior that I would like.

Running the aforementioned `SELECT` query on the following table setup illustrates the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE("Id" VARCHAR(255), "Course" VARCHAR(255), "Day/s" VARCHAR(255), "Sect" VARCHAR(255), "Class Nbr" VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES (1, 'class1', 'M W F', 1134, 553);
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES (2, 'class1', 'T R', 1134, 553);
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES (3, 'class2', 'T R', 1111, 444);
```

The result is:

```
Id  |    Course     |   Day/s   | Sect | Class Nbr
---------------------------------------
 3  |    class2     |    T R    | 1111 | 444
---------------------------------------
1 2 | class1 class1 | M W F T R | 1134 | 553
```

Whereas I'd like the result to be, as it was in MySQL:

```
Id  | Course |   Day/s   | Sect | Class Nbr
---------------------------------------
 3  | class2 |    T R    | 1111 | 444
---------------------------------------
1 2 | class1 | M W F T R | 1134 | 553
```

Any help porting this query over to H2 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your query is being translated into another database engine.  That seems like the simplest explanation for why `GROUP_CONCAT()` becomes `LISTAGG()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query is being used with H2, as shown in the error message, which to my knowledge supports both a ```LISTAGG()``` and a ```GROUP_CONCAT()``` function. So I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: . . I know that `LISTAGG()` does not support `DISTINCT` in Oracle.  I don't know if it does in other databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Based on H2's [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions-aggregate.html#listagg) ```LISTAGG()``` does support ```DISTINCT```. Anyway, I am not sure why the error message is even mentioning ```LISTAGG()```, nor whether that is related to the problem...

Comment: Why not use LISTAGG?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ The ```GROUP_CONCAT()``` query does exactly as needed (in MySQL), and based on H2's documentation, I believe the syntax follows H2's rules. Also, I have never had to use ```LISTAGG()``` before. Therefore, If I cannot get ```GROUP_CONCAT()``` working at all, I have no reason to believe I would be able to get ```LISTAGG()``` working, let alone as desired. Plus, I would like to understand the error that is occurring, for future reference.

Comment: H2 translates this vendor-specific function to a function from the SQL Standard, that's why error message has a rewritten query with another function. The error appears due to invalid use of aggregated column `"Class Nbr"` in the `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL, especially its older versions, accepts many incorrect queries not allowed by others.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov Your comment helped me find the issue. In refactoring, I was generating the query incorrectly. The ```Class Nbr``` column was not supposed to be concatenated. I guess the unexpected error message threw me off. However, now that the sql is running, the result is different than it was using MySQL. I've updated my question to reflect the current problem.

Comment: `DISTINCT` in `GROUP_CONCAT` works well in H2. You need to provide a complete test case with some sample data.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov I added a concrete test case that illustrates the issue

Comment: That's a bug, I filled an issue for it: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2313 (you can remove `ORDER BY` as a workaround, but it may cause different order of values).

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov That's incredible. I've never actually encountered and undiscovered bug like this before, I just assumed I was doing something incorrectly. Thank you so much for filing the bug report!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in H2 1.4.200 and older versions, `DISTINCT` does not work in ordered aggregate functions (`ARRAY_AGG`, `LISTAGG`, and vendor-specific aliases for `LISTAGG`) if whey have an `ORDER BY` clause.

It was fixed and the fix will be included into H2 1.4.201.

To get the fix now you can download the current sources on GitHub:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database
Use a build script with a `jar` target as described here:
https://h2database.com/html/build.html#building

Don't use a Maven build of H2, it is experimental only and it does not produce the fully-featured jar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how is your engine interpreting your sql syntax. But what I can see is that you grouping is based on aggregated column `"Class Nbr"`. Try remove this.

**Using MySQL GROUP_CONCAT:** [(see dbfiddle)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=UI8CubIauy)

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  `Id`ORDER BY  `Id` SEPARATOR ' ') `Id`
  , GROUP_CONCAT( `Course` ORDER BY  `Id` SEPARATOR ' ') `Course`
  , GROUP_CONCAT( `Day/s` ORDER BY  `Id` SEPARATOR ' ') `Day/s` 
  , `Sect`
  , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `Class Nbr` ORDER BY `Id` SEPARATOR ' ') as `Class Nbr` 
FROM `sample_sheet_Copy`
GROUP BY `Sect`
```

**Using ListAgg with Distinct:**

```
SELECT LISTAGG( "Id", ' ' DISTINCT) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Id")  "Id"
  , LISTAGG("Course", ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Id")  "Course"
  , LISTAGG("Day/s", ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Id")  "Day/s"
  , "Sect"
  , LISTAGG("Class Nbr", ' ' DISTINCT) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Id")  as "Class Nbr" 
FROM "sample_sheet_Copy"
GROUP BY "Sect"
```

Comment: Your answer helped me find the issue. In refactoring, I was generating the query incorrectly. The ```Class Nbr``` column was not supposed to be concatenated. I guess the unexpected error message threw me off. However, now that the sql is running, the result is different than it was using MySQL. I've updated my question to reflect the current problem.

Comment: Note that this helped solve an intermediary problem that I was having, but was not the underlying solution for me. See the edited question for a concrete example of the current dilemma.

Comment: @JohnManos, you only need to add course on the column, see updated answer and dbfiddle